# Criar menu de opções

Tags: angular, menu, ionic2

Estou precisando fazer um menu de opções no meu aplicativo desenvolvido em ionic 2. Já rodei a documentação e não achei nada que me ajudasse. Alguém sabe como fazer ? Tem um tutorial ou alguma referencia ? Desde já agradeço.

Esse é o tipo de menu que quero fazer

[image: Esse é o tipo de menu que quero fazer.]

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver usando angular material eles possuem uma grande documentação, o que você quer fazer esta aqui: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menu

Comment: Muito obrigado Marcio , vou estudar para implementar.

Answer (score 1):

Marlon, 
já desenvolvi algo parecido, mas por questões legais eu não posso mostrar o código, porém eu usei o [SlimMenu](https://github.com/adnantopal/slimmenu), é um plugin do JQuery bem fácil de usar, inclusive tem demos no Git. Outra opção que pensei que seria útil para ti é usar [Less CSS](http://lesscss.loopinfinito.com.br/) e fazer um **Sliding menu**, [aqui](https://www.codementor.io/angularjs/tutorial/making-a-sliding-menu-with-directives-less-css) tem um tutorial completo sobre isso, só alterar o botão em si que será resolvido seu problema!

Comment: Valeu Matheus pelas opções, vou estuda-las..